# Not unique/table alias 'respite'

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm a bit confused as to why I am receiving this error.  Here's my (very simple) query.

```
SELECT * FROM consumer_info, respite INNER JOIN respite ON consumer_info.consumer_id = respite.consumer_id;
```

I've even rewritten it and aliased both fields (`consumer_info.consumer_id` and `respite.consumer_id`) to no avail.  I have no clue what could possibly be causing this – any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're selecting from a table you're also joining:

```
SELECT *
FROM consumer_info, respite
                     ^^^^^
INNER JOIN respite ...
            ^^^
```

You can join/use a table multiple times, but each usage of the table MUST have its own unique alias. Try

```
FROM consumer_info, respite
INNER JOIN respite AS somethingelse
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- table alias
```

then `respite.foo` would be using the table copy listed in the `FROM`, and `somethingelse.foo` would be using the copy listed in the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up two join syntaxes - the pre-ANSI and ANSI joins. You should rewrite the statement as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM consumer_info
INNER JOIN respite ON consumer_info.consumer_id = respite.consumer_id;
```

In pre-ANSI syntax the join would look like this (**not recommended**):

```
SELECT *
FROM consumer_info, respite 
WHERE consumer_info.consumer_id = respite.consumer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not set aliases and your join syntax is messy (there are both explicit and implicit `JOIN` syntaxes in your query):

*Explicit syntax:*

```
SELECT * FROM consumer_info ci INNER JOIN respite r ON ci.consumer_id = r.consumer_id;
```

*Implicit syntax:*

```
  SELECT * FROM consumer_info, respite WHERE consumer_info.consumer_id = respite.consumer_id;
```